# Set identification for white Technic panel with sticker that says "5974"

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I would like to know what set these are from. We have 2 of them! Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have

[LegoTechnic, Panel Fairing #18 Large Smooth, Side B with '5974' and Air Intake Pattern (Sticker) - Set 5974](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64682pb003#T=C&C=1)

from  [5974-1: Galactic Enforcer](http://brickset.com/sets/5974-1/Galactic-Enforcer)